# preg match all not saving all matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Here's an example of the text I have to filter:

```
12:00 NAME HTG DAW SDAWERWF 15:00 NUM LEON PARA 20: PEAX SHU MAN POP
```

and I have this regex: `/([0-9]{2})(.*)([0-9]{2})/`

in this code: `preg_match_all ($pattern,$string,$matches);`

Problem is: it saves the first match in `$matches` but the second match isn't saved.

expected output:

```
array(){
 0 => 12
 1 => :00 NAME HTG DAW SDAWERWF
 2 => 15
 3 => :00 NUM LEON PARA
}
```

and so on.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: What is your expected output? Mind there is [only 1 match](https://regex101.com/r/aO5pF3/1) in this string with the current regex.

Comment: Oh yea, sorry let me edit it

Comment: Added another should-be match

Comment: I still don't see expected output in question.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want:

```
$string = '12:00 NAME HTG DAW SDAWERWF 15:00 NUM LEON PARA 20: PEAX SHU MAN POP';

preg_match_all('/(\d\d)(.+?)(?=\d|$)/', $string, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:
            [1] => 00 NAME HTG DAW SDAWERWF 
            [2] => 15:
            [3] => 00 NUM LEON PARA 
            [4] => 20: PEAX SHU MAN POP
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 00
            [2] => 15
            [3] => 00
            [4] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => :
            [1] =>  NAME HTG DAW SDAWERWF 
            [2] => :
            [3] =>  NUM LEON PARA 
            [4] => : PEAX SHU MAN POP
        )

)
```

Comment: [output](http://pastebin.com/BnmnnVh3) I want the first match too without the second match appended to it

Comment: You are getting me an awful lot closer, just gotta get rid of the `:` but I think I can manage that one

Comment: Could you explain me this one? [output](http://pastebin.com/JJyY33e1) Every 7th match has a number added

Comment: Hm, this code does not work if an event does not have an ending time ie: a day off. (which is something we also need to take in account)

Answer (score 0):

combine together all you need

```
$string = "12:00 NAME HTG DAW SDAWERWF 15:00 NUM LEON PARA 20: PEAX SHU MAN POP";
$pattern = '/([0-9]{1,2})(:.*[^\d])([0-9]{1,2})(:.*[^\d])[0-9]{1,2}:/';

preg_match_all ($pattern,$string,$matches);
array_shift($matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) ":00 NAME HTG DAW SDAWERWF "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) ":00 NUM LEON PARA "
  }
}
```

[working](https://eval.in/374840)

Comment: write input and by hand make lines with needed repeats. I don't understand how divide it

Comment: A new line should be started right before every date

Comment: do you want one result for every date ?

Comment: Yes I do, but it's all one giant blob of text

Comment: Unfortunately i can not found points of repetition. Text has difficult structure. I think you do not understand it too.

Comment: Well. I do understand the text, and the only repetition is that everything starts with a date.

Comment: try to split by a date string. Then you will be able to take the 1st match

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
'~\b(:?\d{2}.*?)(?=\h*:?\d{2})~'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qC9vL9/1)